# onChange textarea detection and clear input field

Tags: javascript, input, textarea, onchange

I am trying to clear a input field in a form when the user changes the content of a textarea box with a onchange eventhandler. I don't see where my mistake is why it doesn't work.

Here is my code example: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/giwanesazi/edit?html,js,output)

```js
function clear()
   {  
     document.getElementById('clearme').value= " " ;
     
   }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="clearme" value="123" readonly>
<textarea type="text" id="test2" onChange="clear()">some&#10;text&#10;here</textarea>
```

Comment: Always post your code in your question please.

Comment: You cannot use `clear()` as a function name. Select a new name for your function. / sorry didn't see Barmer's answer post. It didn't show on my mobile for some reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the function name `clear`. This function already exists in the browser, it's used to clear the console window (it probably should have been called `console.clear()`, but it's a top-level function). So your `onchange` is calling that function instead.

Give your function a different name (I used `clearfield()`) and it will work.

```js
function clearfield()
   {  
     document.getElementById('clearme').value= " " ;
     
   }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="clearme" value="123" readonly>
<textarea type="text" id="test2" onChange="clearfield()">some&#10;text&#10;here</textarea>
```